# Azure Function deployment error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/site/repository/node_modules/.bin/semver'

Tags: azure, azure-functions, kudu

I am trying to deploy a Function in node that has dependencies into a Linux container.  According to the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node) if there is a package.json it should run `npm install` and be fine.  However I get the following:

```
Command: "/home/site/deployments/tools/deploy.sh"
Handling function App deployment.
Not using funcpack because SCM_USE_FUNCPACK is not set to 1
Installing azure function extensions from nuget
Kudu sync from: '/home/site/repository' to: '/home/site/wwwroot'
Copying file: '.gitignore'
Copying file: 'README.md'
Copying file: 'host.json'
Copying file: 'package-lock.json'
Copying file: 'package.json'
Copying file: 'proxies.json'
Ignoring: .git
Copying file: 'node_modules/.bin/semver'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/semver'
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
Kudu Sync failed
\n/opt/Kudu/bin/Scripts/starter.sh "/home/site/deployments/tools/deploy.sh"
```

After getting into the container (https://XXX.scm.azurewebsites.net) Is it because semver is a link to a file?
Anybody else have this issue and anyway to get around it?

Comment: fixed it in end by removing semver dependency.

Comment: You could add an answer for others to refer.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the semver dependency.  I'm not convinced Kudu plays nicely with linked files

Comment: The deployment mechanism for Functions (zip deploy) currently doesn't handle symlinks well. We have a work item out to fix this.

Comment: How did you remove the semver dependency?