# Nodejs Azure Deployment Failure: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/semver'

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment, azure-pipelines

A couple days ago our production release pipeline started to fail with the following error:

```
2020-10-17T00:14:13.1233435Z Omitting next output lines...
2020-10-17T00:14:13.1234108Z Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/semver'
2020-10-17T00:14:13.1234825Z An error has occurred during web site deployment.
2020-10-17T00:14:13.1235127Z Kudu Sync failed
2020-10-17T00:14:13.1235451Z \n/opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh "/home/site/deployments/tools/deploy.sh"
2020-10-17T00:14:13.1265401Z ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
2020-10-17T00:14:13.1276348Z ##[error]Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.
2020-10-17T00:14:13.6429241Z Successfully updated deployment History at https://{omitted}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/{omitted}
2020-10-17T00:14:13.6510314Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Azure App Service
```

The pipeline will successfully complete all tests/scripts + publish the drop artifact. The release process starts but fails on the deployment step with the error above.

[image: Pipeline image]

I've attempted to roll back to the last working commit that **did** deploy successfully and it will still fail on this step.

I've spent a few days trying to resolve this and haven't had any luck. Any ideas would cause something like this to randomly start happening?

I can provide additional information about our stack if it'll help debug this.

**EDIT**

My current app settings:

[image: App settings]

`azure-pipelines.yml`

```
trigger:
- master

variables:

  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureSubscription: '9690121f-a50b-43c0-8d1b-e8ca6533b2d5'
  
  # Web app name
  webAppName: 'hidden'
  
  # Environment name
  environmentName: 'hidden'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
      
    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '12.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - task: YarnInstaller@3
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '1.22.4'
      displayName: 'Install Yarn'

    - script: |
        yarn install
        yarn build
        yarn test:e2e
      displayName: 'Build and test'
      
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool: 
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:            
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: hidden'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: 'webAppLinux'
              appName: '$(webAppName)'
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              runtimeStack: 'NODE|12.x'
              startUpCommand: 'node dist/main'
```

Comment: Have you tried to removed the semver dependency. It seems Kudu could not plays nicely with linked files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52983708/azure-function-deployment-error-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-stat. BTW, Does this problem occur randomly or does it always exist?

Comment: Without knowing your context, just because of the coincidental timing, any chance that you use certificate pinning and MS rolled it over in your app. They recently started rolling certs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/tls-certificate-changes Any chance this is related?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Semver is not a directly dependency of ours. Since the deployment last ran successfully I've only installed one additional dependency (js-yaml). I've tried rolling back to the last commit that didn't include this dependency and it still fails. So one of the existing deps I had installed must use it I guess? I can repro this issue on every deployment attempt.

Comment: @LeftyGBalogh I'm not sure what certificate pinning is - but, our certs for the production domain do come from Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to workaround this issue by creating a new App Service + a new pipeline attached to our existing repo.

Both the pipeline + App service are exactly the same as the old ones.

For whatever reason deploying on the new setup worked. It's not an exact solution to the original question I posted, but, I'm happy that I can deploy code now. If someone else is running into the same issue I would suggest trying the same thing I did.

Answer (score 4):

While this is not a root cause solution, I find it a more convenient workaround than the accepted answer since it does not require setting up a new Web App.

I had the same issue with a semver dependency in an Azure Web app yesterday. I finally solved it by [ssh-ing into the web app container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_create_remote_connection) and deleting the directory `/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules`.

I have not fully figured out what's causing this, but it seems to be something with the Kudu deployment tools that do not play well with the symlinks in the `/node_modules/.bin` folder.

Comment: Any update on this topic? Sshing to PaaS web app does not seem to be the best way to do so

Comment: I had a similar issue with a `node_modules/.bin/node-sass` and this solution worked! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your App Service and check in Application Settings if there is a variable **`'WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM'`** and set it to true.

Restart the App Service. Wait for 20 seconds, then redeploy your application.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added that variable and still got the same error I posted above. I'll include a screenshot of my current app settings